# AS3: Images are randomly disappearing from stage

Tags: image, actionscript-3

I'm working on a game that asks students to click on a given state (the word is shown, like "Indiana", they have to click on the states. On the stage I have an image of the USA, with only the state borders, and then 50 images (in a "state" array) of each state. Each individual image is copied onto a transparent image the size of the outlined USA image, thereby allowing it to be placed exactly where it goes. After about the 24th image is put on stage, the 1st image disappears. When the 25th image is added to the stage, the 2nd image disappears. I have no idea why. Any advice? (ignore my misspellings of the state file names)
[(Image of USA with missing states)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3ku6.png)

```
        package 
    {
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;

        /**
         * ...
         * @author Brian King
         */
        public class Main extends Sprite 
        {   //states
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Alabama.png")]
                public var alabamaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Alaska.png")]
                public var alaskaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Arizona.png")]
                public var arizonaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Arkansas.png")]
                public var arkansasPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/California.png")]
                public var californiaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Colorado.png")]
                public var coloradoPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Connecticut.png")]
                public var connecticutPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Delaware.png")]
                public var delawarePic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Florida.png")]
                public var floridaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Georgia.png")]
                public var georgiaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Hawaii.png")]
                public var hawaiiPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Idaho.png")]
                public var idahoPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Illnois.png")]
                public var illinoisPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Indiana.png")]
                public var indianaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Iowa.png")]
                public var iowaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Kansas.png")]
                public var kansasPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Kentucky.png")]
                public var kentuckyPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Loisiana.png")]
                public var loisianaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Maine.png")]
                public var mainePic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Maryland.png")]
                public var marylandPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Massachusetts.png")]
                public var massachusettsPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Michigan.png")]
                public var michiganPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Minnesota.png")]
                public var minnesotaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Mississippi.png")]
                public var mississippiPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Missouri.png")]
                public var missouriPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Nebraska.png")]
                public var nebraskaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Nevada.png")]
                public var nevadaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/NewHampshire.png")]
                public var newhapshirePic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/NewJersey.png")]
                public var newjerseyPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/NewMexico.png")]
                public var newmexicoPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/NewYork.png")]
                public var newyorkPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/NorthCarolina.png")]
                public var northcarolinaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/NorthDakota.png")]
                public var northdakotaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Ohio.png")]
                public var ohioPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Oklahoma.png")]
                public var oklahomaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Oregon.png")]
                public var oregonPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Pennsylvania.png")]
                public var pennsylvaniaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/RhodeIsland.png")]
                public var rhodeIslandPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/SouthCarolina.png")]
                public var southcarolinaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/SouthDekota.png")]
                public var southdadotaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Tennessee.png")]
                public var tennesseePic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Texas.png")]
                public var texasPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Utah.png")]
                public var utahPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Vermont.png")]
                public var vermontPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Virginia.png")]
                public var virginiaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Washington.png")]
                public var washingtonPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/WestVirginia.png")]
                public var westvirginiaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source="../lib/Wisconsin.png")]
                public var wisconsinPic:Class;      
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Montana.png")]
                public var montanaPic:Class;
                [Embed(source = "../lib/Wyoming.png")]
                public var wyomingPic:Class;

            public function Main():void 
            {
                if (stage) init();
                else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            }

            private function init(e:Event = null):void 
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
                // entry point


                var state:Array = new Array();
                    state.push(new alabamaPic());
                    state.push(new alaskaPic());
                    state.push(new arizonaPic());
                    state.push(new arkansasPic());
                    state.push(new californiaPic());
                    state.push(new coloradoPic());
                    state.push(new connecticutPic());
                    state.push(new delawarePic());
                    state.push(new floridaPic());
                    state.push(new georgiaPic());
                    state.push(new hawaiiPic());
                    state.push(new idahoPic());
                    state.push(new illinoisPic());
                    state.push(new indianaPic());
                    state.push(new iowaPic());
                    state.push(new kansasPic());
                    state.push(new kentuckyPic());
                    state.push(new loisianaPic());
                    state.push(new mainePic());
                    state.push(new marylandPic());
                    state.push(new massachusettsPic());
                    state.push(new michiganPic());
                    state.push(new minnesotaPic());
                    state.push(new mississippiPic());
                    state.push(new missouriPic());          
                    state.push(new montanaPic());
                    state.push(new nebraskaPic());
                    state.push(new nevadaPic());
                    state.push(new newhapshirePic());
                    state.push(new newjerseyPic());
                    state.push(new newmexicoPic());
                    state.push(new newyorkPic());
                    state.push(new northcarolinaPic());
                    state.push(new northdakotaPic());
                    state.push(new ohioPic());
                    state.push(new oklahomaPic());
                    state.push(new oregonPic());
                    state.push(new pennsylvaniaPic());
                    state.push(new rhodeIslandPic());
                    state.push(new southcarolinaPic());
                    state.push(new southdadotaPic());
                    state.push(new tennesseePic());
                    state.push(new texasPic());
                    state.push(new utahPic());
                    state.push(new vermontPic());
                    state.push(new virginiaPic());
                    state.push(new washingtonPic());
                    state.push(new westvirginiaPic());
                    state.push(new wisconsinPic());
                    state.push(new wyomingPic());

                var counter:int = 0;
                counter = 0;
                    while (counter < 50) {
                        addChild(state[counter]);
                        counter++;
                    }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's weird, your code looks fine ! Try to put more details or more code or maybe your fla (if it's possible of course) ...

Comment: Thanks, akmozo. I'll add some code when I get back to the comp with the source. I have a hunch it's with all the overlapping transparency (though I cannot understand why - each image is a PNG file). I'll add more code in a bit.

Comment: Probably so, BotMaster, but I'm an amateur, just learning. Could you at least offer some advice?

Comment: If you are amator then fair enough. First you have to show all the code not just a sample of it. Second since you add all your asset to an array then loop that array to add them to the display list and don't use a while loop.

Comment: @BrianKing You have some problems in your code but I don't see why you have the problem that you'v mentioned. Some remarks : if you don't really need that a property or a method to be `public` don't set it as `public`, if you can use a `for` loop don't use a `while` one to avoid infinite loops, don't put your methods and attributes inside the constructor of your class, don't forget to set the params of your events handlers, don't put all your code inside one method, try to use a method for each task to get a clean an more readable code (create_States, create_TextFields, add_Listeners, ...) ...

Comment: Thanks so much, akmozo! I really enjoy this learning process. Perhaps the problem is the fact that I'm "stacking" 50 different images (all the size of the screen) and that many is causing the transparency (of the background) to become opaque. I don't know; I still have a lot to learn and I'm thankful for the direction you've given me. I've edited the code above from a more basic "project" with ONLY the states, hoping that would solve the problem. No luck.

Comment: @BotMaster: Why would I loop an array where I only need to add 1 instance of each object into the array? That would give me multiple copies of each object, causing major problems on the stage. (Just wanting to learn.)

Comment: I'll just cut them down to size and place them on the map manually. Thanks for the time you gave trying to help.

Comment: Problem solved! Apparently when you stack multiple transparent backgrounds (PNG files), they combine to become opaque. (I've seen this occur with sprite sheets before.)